# Trouble using Spring EL with default variable to fetch from value from properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I am trying to use SpEL to resolve a variable from my application.yml file, but I am running into some issues.

My application.yml file looks like this:

```
myapp:
  componentOne:
    name: "helloWorld"
```

A separate .yml file looks like this:

```
other:
  config: "componentOne"
```

I am trying to use Spring `SpelExpressionParser` as follows:

```
public MyClass {
  @Autowired
  Helper helper;

  public StringValueResolver stringResolver;

  public void someMethod() {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#environment['myapp.' + helper.getVar() + '.name']");
    String name = exp.getValue(String.class);
  }
}
```

OR

```
public void someMethod() {
  ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
  Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#environment['myapp.' + stringResolver.resolveStringValue(helper.getVar()) + '.name']");
  String name = exp.getValue(String.class);
}
```

`helper.getVar()` outputs *${other.config}* and `stringResolver.resolveStringValue(helper.getVar())` outputs *componentOne* both as expected

I get the following error for the above code blocks respectively:

```
EL1007E: Property or field 'helper' cannot be found on null
```

OR

```
EL1007E: Property or field 'stringResolver' cannot be found on null
```

I know Spring can resolve my variable because when I test a SpEL expression using any annotation, for example `@Value`, the variable is resolved properly. All examples below work and I end up with *helloWorld* from the application.yml file:

```
@Value("#{environment['myapp.' + '${other.config}' + '.name']}")
@Value("#{environment['myapp.componentOne.name']}")
@MyCustomAnno("#{environment['myapp.' + '${other.config}' + '.name']}")
@MyCustomAnno("#{environment['myapp.componentOne.name']}")
```

I can't use ${other.config} because that is provided to the `Helper` class and is used here so I need to use the `helper.getVar()` method, and the .yml files can look different depending on the module. E.g.:

```
other:
  config: "componentTwo"
```

```
myapp:
  componentTwo:
    name: "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register your helper as a rootObject to the Expression.
Then your "getVar()" method is made available to the evaluator.

> **Expression.getValue(Object rootObject, Class desiredResultType)**
>
> Evaluate the expression in the default context against the specified
> root object.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/Expression.html

i.e.

```
public void someMethod() {
  ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
  Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("#environment[new String('myapp.') + getVar() + new String('.name')]");
  String name = exp.getValue(helper, String.class);
}
```

There's more information on this stuff here:

[6.5.5 Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#:%7E:text=multi%2Ddimensional%20array.-,6.5.5%C2%A0Methods,-Methods%20are%20invoked)

Look at how "societyContext" is used as a root object there, it provides access to it's method "isMember". *(Search through the page for the 10 occurrences of isMember for examples/insight)*

[Society.java](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#:%7E:text=.country%20%3D%20country%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09%0A%09%0A%7D-,Society.java,-package%20org.spring)

Comment: Changing my code to the above yields the following error - ```EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value```. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I suspect that is caused by the `#environment[]` part. Note that you've excluded the curly braces in the SPEL `#env...`, where your @Value has it like `#{env...`. You should incrementally rule out the root cause of the problem by starting with just `"#environment['myapp.helloWorld.name']"`. If that works, then check this one `"new String('myapp.') + getVar() + new String('.name')"` and see what it evaluates to. This could all be achieved pretty quickly with some unit testing and debugging.